# How do I taper the density of volume edges?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, shader-nodes

I'm creating a smoke cloud just run by the displace modifier, and want a simple volume texture, but would like to have softer edges all around the model.

I have tried gradient textures (quadratic sphere) but it's only clumping around the object's origin.

Anyway to have a gradient driven by the normals of the object so they're just inset from the object's edges all around?

[image: gradient clumping around origin]

[image: edge density too hard]